# Store Images from web into folder and read from it

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I would like to know what is best way to store images from internet in folder and read from folder because later on I will need to show them in gallery. Should I store them to external or internal storage, should I give user option to choose storage if his memory is low or? Also how should I optimize it so it doesn't take too much space. Generally I need some idea how to make it fast, stable and optimized for devices with no memory card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Oncreate() method

```
  getBitmapFromURL(data);
```

where data is the image url.

then

```
   public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        String filename;
        Date date = new Date(0);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        filename = sdf.format(n);
        File myDir=new File("/sdcard/Pictures");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
      //  filename = sdf.format(date);
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved to Light Box",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // 5
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }

}
```